# addView table with linearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I  doing a program that I create View with java , I want table the buttons . I don´t understand what happen .

this is the code:

public class Snake extends Activity {

```
LinearLayout layout [] = new LinearLayout[10];
Button boton[][] = new Button [10][10];
LinearLayout snake = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.snake);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_snake);

    //LayoutParams fillWrap = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   // LayoutParams wrapWrap = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.length; i++) {        
        layout [i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout[i].setId(i);
        layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        snake.addView(layout[i]);

        for (int j = 0; j < layout.length; j++) {
            boton[i][j] = new Button(this);
            boton[i][j].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            if ((i == 5) && (j ==5)) {
                boton[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            } else {
                boton[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);                 
            }
            layout[i].addView(boton[i][j]);
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the layout orientation.Also you need to set the layoutparams width LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT

```
layout[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout[i].setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```